I been trying to add icons from fluent ui northstar into fluent ui dropdown.. There is no proper documentation available
I tried with render Item to add a divider and Icon to fluent ui drop but icons are not visible
even the default value not showing the icons and the dropdown is not showing up after clicking
import * as React from "react";
import { Dropdown, DropdownItemProps, Flex, Text } from "@fluentui/react-northstar";
import { AcceptIcon, TeamsIcon } from "@fluentui/react-icons-northstar";

interface CustomDropdownItemProps extends DropdownItemProps {
  icon: React.ReactNode;
  key: string;
  kind?: "divider";
}

const items = [
  {
    key: "myMatters",
    header: "My matters",
    
    icon: <AcceptIcon />,
  },

  {
    kind: "divider" as const,
  },
  {
    key: "teamName1",
    header: "Team Name",
    
    icon: <TeamsIcon />,
  },
];

const renderItem = (item: any) => (
  <Flex gap="gap.smaller" vAlign="center">
    {item.icon}
    <Text content={item.header as string} />
  </Flex>
);

export const DropdownMenu: React.FC = () => (
  <Dropdown
    items={items}
    placeholder="Select an option"
    defaultValue={items[0]}
    checkable
    renderItem={renderItem}
    inline
  />
);


Judging by that repositories documentation, it doesn't accept an icon or a component as its props.
You can however provide an image string:
https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/0.66.2/components/dropdown/props#dropdown-item
const items = [
  {
    key: "myMatters",
    header: "My matters",
    image: '../path/to/icon.png',
  }
];

So you could download the svgs from the library or maybe try and turn them into a base64 string and pass that.
